# Structure map and life cycle of UnitOfWork Class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ef-code-first, structuremap

I use structuremap library and following code to config DI in a WinForm App:

```
 private static void InitializeStructureMap()
        {
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.For<IUnitOfWork>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use
                    <CouponContext>();


                x.For<ICouponService>().Use<EFCouponService>();
                x.For<IUserService>().Use<EFUserService>();
            });
        }
```

also i use following code to GetInstance of Classes in a form:

```
private IUnitOfWork uow;
private IUserService userService;

public LoginForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    uow = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
    userService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUserService>();
}
```

How is the life cycle of UnitOfWork in my App?

Comment: If you are building a Windows Forms application, why do you use a HttpContext scoped lifestyle?

Comment: Not Difference between "HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped" and "ThreadLocal" in Windows Forms Application.

Comment: There actually is a difference. This will ensure the System.Web assembly gets loaded, which is quite bizarre for a forms application and costs memory and load time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default it's per request, but you can configure it

```
x.For<IUnitOfWork>()
 .LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.Singleton))
```

From documentation:

```
PerRequest - The default operation.  A new instance will be created for each request.
Singleton - A single instance will be shared across all requests
ThreadLocal - A single instance will be created for each requesting thread.  Caches the instances with ThreadLocalStorage.
HttpContext - A single instance will be created for each HttpContext.  Caches the instances in the HttpContext.Items collection.
HttpSession - A single instance will be created for each HttpSession.  Caches the instances in the HttpContext.Session collection.  Use with caution.
Hybrid - Uses HttpContext storage if it exists, otherwise uses ThreadLocal storage.
```